# converting a chr into num in R

Tags: r, char, converters, var

I have some data that is currently in character form, and I need to put it into numeric form so that I can get the mean. I'm new to R so any help will be much appreciated. My initial thought was that the missing data is causing it to not be read as num, but could it be because the numbers are "3" instead of 3?

Here's what I have:

```
X
chr [1:1964] "3", "4", "4", "1", NA
```

I've tried different methods of converting `X` from `chr` to `num`:

---

```
X <- na.omit(Y, Z, as.numeric)
mean(X)
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In mean.default(X) :
#  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

---

```
X <- c(Y, Z, na.rm=TRUE)
mean(X, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In mean.default(X, na.rm = TRUE) :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

---

```
X <- c(Y, Z, na.rm=TRUE)
str(X)
#  Named chr [1:1965] "3" "4" "4" "1" "5" "7" NA "6" NA "5" ...
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1965] "" "" "" "" ...
```

Comment: `mean(as.numeric(X),na.rm=T)` ??

Comment: Did you try `as.numeric(X)`?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate.  The question is, which one to choose?

Comment: so as.numeric(x) works!  but now i'm faced with trying to remove the missing data "NA" so that I can do calculations.

Comment: i used na.omit and as.numeric to remove the NA's and keep it as numeric.

Answer (score 1):

As always, an example of your actual data is helpful. I think I can answer anyway, though. If your data are character data, then converting to numeric like this will work most of the time:

```
 X2 <- as.numeric(X)
```

If you have missing values, are they showing up as NA? Or did you write something else there to indicate missingness such as "missing"? If you've got something other than NA in your original data, then when you do the `as.numeric(X)` conversion, R will convert those values to NA and give you a warning message.

To take the mean of a numeric object that has missing values, use:

```
 mean(X2, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Laura,  The missing values are showing up as NA, I didn't put that there to indicate missingness.                                   > ffa <- as.numeric(FamFriendAccept)
> 
> mean(ffa)
[1] NA                                                              > ffa <- as.numeric(FamFriendAccept, na.rm=TRUE)
> 
> mean(ffa)
[1] NA
> mean(ffa,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 5.460305

Comment: Thanks!  So that worked to get the mean.  If i need to compare that mean to another mean, would I have to input  na.rm=TRUE for every computation?

Comment: Yes. For example, to do a t test on two objects where either have NA values, you would write `t.test(A, B, na.rm=T)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
mean(as.numeric(X), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Doing the `as.numeric()` will introduce an `NA` for values like "X" and many of the summary functions have a `na.rm` parameter to ignore `NA` values in the vector.

But of course taking the mean of a list of chromosomes is a pretty weird operation.

Comment: @BondedDust Hehe. No. I guess i read the question wrong. I thought it was talking about chromosomes in there somewhere. I guess i've been working with genetic data for too long.

Comment: In R "chr" is `"character"`.

Comment: @BondedDust I know I know. But seeing numbers between 1 and 22 and X's and Y's i get easily confused. I guess the real question is why did those get imported as characters to begin with.